# SpriteKit: Rotate a node based on a calculated angle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation, sprite-kit

So I am writing a game in which an archer shoots an arrow at a target. The shot velocity and angle are determined by using the x and y components of the line formed by the user dragging their finger across the screen. The effect I am having trouble achieving here is having my archers arm be rotated at the same angle as the line mentioned above forms with the ground

I calculate the angle in a controller class I wrote like so (Not sure if all the casting is bad :[ )

```
+(CGFloat)calculateAngleToRotateByGivenX:(CGFloat)xComponent Y:(CGFloat)yComponent{
   double oppOverAdj = (double)yComponent/(double)xComponent;
   return -(CGFloat)atan(oppOverAdj);
```

Then I give that calculated angle to my Archer node to use to rotate the arm

```
-(void)rotateArmByAngle:(CGFloat)angle{
   SKAction *rotateArmBy = [SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:0 shortestUnitArc:YES];
   [[self childNodeWithName:@"upperArm"]runAction:rotateArmBy];    
}
```

all put together in the scene it looks like this

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint previousPosotion = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
    [player rotateArmByAngle:[PSSpriteController calculateAngleToRotateByGivenX:intialTouchPosotion.x-currentPosition.x Y:initialTouchPosition.y-currentPosition.y]];   
}
```

When testing, the arm rotates but not quite to the angle I would expect it to. I'm looking for any suggestions to get what I have working or if there is an entirely different approach I should be taking I'd love to give that a shot too, thanks. Also let me know if there is any more info that would be useful.

Comment: Can you show the difference between what you're expecting and what's actually happening?

Comment: It looks like it works okay from 0 to 180deg then it flips and faces the wrong direction. Here's with it working http://imgur.com/PWDjwuW and here's with it flipped the wrong direction http://imgur.com/tfcW2ah

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to rotate the sprite based on the user's touch position:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    float deltaX = positionInScene.x;
    float deltaY = positionInScene.y;

    float angle = atan2f(deltaY, deltaX) + M_PI_2;

    player.zRotation = angle;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, that method is a little off because it needs to be calculated in regards to the initial location of the touch. However, you brought to attention that I didn't add M_PI_2 which fixed my problem once I did, so thank you!

Comment: @Jaicob How did you do it bro? I tried it, but didn't work :(